# javascript/jquery combine hidden inputs as var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of tags which all get added to a hidden input with name="item[tags][]"

```
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="first" name="item[tags][]">
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="second" name="item[tags][]">
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="third" name="item[tags][]">
```

How could i combine those hidden inputs to output

```
var tag_filter = first,second,third;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use name selector to access the input elements and use map function along with get and join to get the comma separated list of values.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/mGmRH/)**

```
var tag_filter = $('[name="item[tags][]"]').map(function(){
  return this.value;
}).get().join();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this

```
var str = "";
$('input[name="item[tags][]"]').each(function(){
    str += $(this).val()+","
})
str = str.substring(0,str.length);
```